# BeautifulSoup scraping not finding all 'a' tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some code, which used to work but due to changes on the website no longer does.
I am trying to grab all the `a` tags from an Apple page in order to compile a list of the deprecated methods - like the ones listed here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore?language=objc

These methods which may contain deprecated methods can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technologies/

Which lists the methods by section - here is one for Accelerate,

`<a data-v-2c210164="" data-v-012d2acf="" href="/documentation/accelerate" class="card" aria-labelledby="card_title_26" aria-describedby="card_content_26"><div data-v-2c210164="" class="card__content"><p data-v-2c210164="" id="card_title_26" aria-label="Accelerate" class="card__title">Accelerate</p></a>`

Despite being an `a` tag, the following code does not pick up `/documentation/accelerate` in the href tags, but picks up other links on the page such as the footer.

```
headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
        }

url = "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technologies"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')


for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print str(a)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have also tried other matches, such as `for a in soup.find_all('a', class_=card):` but this also didn't pick anything up.
My guess is that it could be pulled from Javascript or something?

Comment: You are right, the data is getting pulled from javascript. You should try this using `selenium`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What happens?

If you take a look in your soup, you will determine, that there is no such `<a>` in the response. So you could not find it.

Reason is, page is dealing with dynamic content.

### How to fix that?

You can use selenium to grab the `page_source` cause selenium can handle the dynamic content very well:

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technologies"

driver.get(url)
sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')


for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(a)
    
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thought as much, thank you.
For anyone else finding this issue - if you are on macOS, you will need chromedriver
`brew install chromedriver`
and remove `executable_path=` from the above answer